# How do you pass a typedef struct to a function?

Tags: c, arrays, function, struct

At the moment I'm trying

```
void avg(everything)
```

But that gives me the error:

```
error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer
```

And when I got this error earlier today it was because I wasn't passing a 2D array to the function properly. So I figure this is the same but I can't find the correct format to pass it in.

This is my typedef:

```
typedef struct structure
{
char names[13][9];
int scores[13][4];
float average[13];
char letter[13];
} stuff;
```

And this is my typedef array:

```
stuff everything[13];
```

Comment: So... what is "everything"?

Comment: `void avg(stuff *p);` would seem to fit the bill.

Comment: function needs to be defined as `void avg(stuff * s) {}` - but the call needs to `avg(everything);`

Comment: @WhozCraig Worked great, thanks. Probably should've thought of that one myself but wasn't sure if there was something specific I didn't know about.

Comment: @Xerinos if you're *always* passing a hard-size automatic array in, then you can skip the length-parameter by declaring your formal parameter to be `void arg(stuff (*ar)[ARRAY_SIZE]);`, where `ARRAY_SIZE` is the hard-dimension. Note: This means this function can *only* take a regular array of that size as a parameter. You would have to cast to pass something different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the function signature, you need to specify the type, not the specific name of a variable you want to pass in. Further, if you want to pass an array, you need to pass a pointer (you should probably be passing structs by pointers anyway, otherwise a copy of the data will be made each time you call the function). Hence you function should look like:

```
void avg(stuff* s);
```

However, C arrays also have no concept of length. Hence, you should always pass in the length of the array to the function:

```
void avg(stuff* s, size_t len);
```

You'd then call this as follows:

```
avg(everything, 13);
```

Also, if the function doesn't modify the data in any way, you should signify this by specifying that the parameter is `const`:

```
void avg(const stuff* s, size_t len);
```

Comment: "C arrays also have no concept of length" -- Incorrect. You're probably referring to the fact that a pointer to the first element of an array doesn't indicate the length of the array. On the other hand, given `int arr[42];`, the length of `arr` is 42.

Answer (score 4):

A type introduced with `typedef` is an alias that can be used for a real type.

For example:

```
typedef struct some_struct { ... } some_type_name;
```

Now you can use `some_type_name` *instead* of `struct some_struct`.

So when declaring a function which takes a structure of this "type" you use the type like any other type:

```
void some_function(some_type_name var) { ... }
```

In `some_function` as defined above, you can use `var` like a normal structure variable.

To define a function taking an array (or a pointer) to this type, that's equally simple:

```
void some_function(some_type_name *pointer) { ... }
```