# Can't pass typedef struct to function by reference

Tags: c, arrays, reference, typedef

I'm trying to pass a custom type object to a function by reference, and I can't figure out what I could be doing wrong.  I read [How do you pass a typedef struct to a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16159712/how-do-you-pass-a-typedef-struct-to-a-function) as well as other references and could swear I'm already doing exactly that.  I cleared out everything else I'm doing and even this spartan code throws 5 errors.  Help me, Stackexchange; You're my only hope!

The goal is simply to be able to alter the values in the array in the object.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
typedef struct structure {
    char byte[10];
    char mod;
} complex;
void simpleInit (complex *a, char value) {//put the value in the first byte and zero the rest
    a.byte[0] = value;
    char i;
    for (i = 1; i < 10; ++i) {
        a.byte[i] = 0;
    }
    a.mod = 1;
}
void main () {
    complex myNumber;
    char value = 6;
    simpleInit (myNumber, value);
}
```

When I attempt to run this I get this error and 4 similar:

> test2.c:10:3: error: request for member ‘byte’ in something not a structure or union
>
> a.byte[0] = value;

Comment: `a.byte` --> `a->byte`

Comment: `simpleInit` expected a `complex *` for its first argument.  `myNumber` has type `complex`, not `complex *`.  You need to pass `&myNumber` to `simpleInit`.  It has nothing to do with `typedef`.  This is true for any basic C data type.

Comment: You need to learn the language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a` is a pointer type, so you need to de-reference it to use it. Typically that's done with the arrow operator:

```
a->byte[i] = 0;
```

Since this is just an array of bytes you can also quickly "zero" it:

```
memset(a, 0, 10);
```

Though given how important `10` is in your code you should codify that in a constant or a `#define`.

Comment: Or use `sizeof(a->byte)`, though the loop index then needs to be an unsigned type (e.g. `size_t`) to avoid signed-unsigned comparison warnings, if they're enabled.

Comment: My actual code does use #define, and it's not 10 either.  This was just a massively scaled down version of something I'm making to handle numbers larger than 64 bits (like a homemade mini-gmp).
I will get much use from the memset function too, thanks.
I also was failing to pass a reference with &, as Tom Karzes pointed out in his comment.

Comment: `memset` will be a life-saver if you're initializing much larger arrays, then. It's way more efficient than setting byte by byte.

Answer (score 1):

When you pass a value by reference you need to use asterisk to access al fields of the structure, for example:

```
(*a).byte[0] = value;
```

Happily you have -> as a shortcut, so this will be:

```
a->byte[0] = value;
```

Also do not forget to call the & (address of) operator when you call `simpleInit`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef struct structure 
{
    char byte[10];
    char mod;
} complex;

void simpleInit (complex *a, char value) 
{
    char i;

    a->byte[0] = value;

    for (i = 1; i < 10; ++i) {
        a->byte[i] = 0;
    }

    a->mod = 1;
}

int main() 
{ 
    complex myNumber;
    char value = 6;
    simpleInit (&myNumber, value);
}
```

Comment: Thank you this is perfect.  I already accepted the other perfect answer, but yours is exactly identical to my corrected code. :)
I spent hours trying to figure this out!